# JSON Feed on my wordpress Blog

Tags: plugins, json, plugin-json-api

I have just installed 2 plugins for JSON feed for my blog as I need to develop an Android Application for the same.

Plugins used :

1.) http://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-json/
2.) /plugins/json-rest-api/

The first one is at url : http://droidacid.com/feed/json - But it is not generating proper JSON for me... I'm not getting any JSONObject or anything so not able to parse it.

In second one **/wp-json/posts** I'm getting some date time issues.

Can anyone help me with the same as I need anyone of them to work for parsing.

Thanks

Note : As I dont have 10 rep so was not able to post full links.

Comment: Look carefully at the json feed. There is a warning very end of the json string. `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() [<a href='function.call-user-func-array'>function.call-user-func-array</a>]: ...` Which making it invalid. Try to resolve that error.

Comment: I found out a working solution here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-call_user_func_array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback